# Remove unnecessary images from xcode project

Tags: iphone, xcode, image

I have lots of images in my xcode project for iPhone application. i have changed some of images in last 2-3 version but now i want to remove unnecessary images from that.

I tried `ctrl + Shift + F` to find image name in whole project but i am not able to sure that i am using images through xib(interface Builder) or not.

so how to find images are in use through xib file or in project or let me know if you have any other trick for this.

Answer (score 3):

Try Slender, it's designed just for that :

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/slender/id493656257?mt=12

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Actually i am working on snow leopard 10.6.8 and Slender require lion OS. do you have any other alternative for this?

Comment: Sorry I don't know any equivalent for Snow Leopard :/